How do I fix this wall with caulk ridges?
How do I fix this paint/wall?
I recently did my first DIY accent wall. I’m a complete YouTube DIYer and have zero experience doing any of these things so I’ve had a lot of errors along the way.
I did caulking of the vertical panels to get a smooth finish, but it looks like when I used my finger to rub it off some rubbed on the drywall. I didn’t notice until after I painted. It has this raised edge that can be seen when close. I’ve attached two photos to show how bad it looks.
I have plenty of paint so repainting won’t be a problem. But how do I fix this?



You can probably scrape away the caulk ridge with a putty knife. Press it flat to the wall and gently nudge it along, attempting to shave it flat. If it's not going well, try a sharper tool, such as a razor blade. Do your best to not scar up the paint.
Once that's done you may need to skim with spackle or joint compound to repair any scars and further conceal the ridge. Seek to minimize any such application. Rather than sanding, use a lightly damp cloth to rub out any imperfections. Pay particular attention to the edges, and try to feather out the patch into the paint stipple.
Then repaint.


Heat the area with blow dryer or heat gun.
Caulk will go soft and that should allow you to remove it without taking out chunks of paint.
Remove caulk with flat edge razor.   You need to remove all not just make it flat with paint.  (You need to remove that huge paint run on the other side just like this too)
Sand area - so 3-4" on both sides
Fill in with joint compound (drywall mud).   You can scrape the area pretty hard to get it flat right away.
Sand the next day.
Can repaint right after sanding.

Steps 1-6 should take 20-60 mins albeit you have to wait for the mud to dry.
